# Texture won't appear while rendering

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, texturing, uv

[image: theproblem]

1) I added a material
2) Marked seams on a mesh, unwrapped and drawn a texture for UV map in external image editor
3) loaded texture in texture shaders and in UV/image editor, as you can see the names are match
4) added texture coordinate shader connected it's "UV" output to texture shaders' "vector" inputs

the texture shows up correctly in textured view and material view,
but completely disappears in rendered view if i set image extension to "repeat" or "extend",
and appears completely black if i set extension to "clip"

what should i do to show it up?

Comment: If it appears in preview but not during render it is possibily a modifier issue. Check your modifier stack for different settings

Comment: plesase show an image of the complete node tree for the material